# User Profile Incremental Synchronization Timer Job runs on wrong server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have configured 2 User Profile Service instance's on a SharePoint 2010 farm to cater for an Intranet and Extranet Domain.  One UPS runs on the app server and hosts the Intranet sync and the other runs on the extranet server hosting the extranet sync.  Both servers have the User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service running.

We have noticed that sometimes the Incremental Sync job for the Intranet is actually running on the extranet server and reports the following error in the 'Failed Timer Job' list in central admin - *The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)*

The current SharePoint patch level (build version) for each environment is 14.0.6120.5006 (SharePoint 2010 Server with SP1 and April 2012 CU applied).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Remote WMI.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx

if the farm contains multiple servers running SharePoint Server 2010, and two or more servers are running the User Profile service, the timer job responsible for synchronization might fail. This happens when the server that runs the synchronization timer job is not running the synchronization service. To resolve this problem, grant the farm account the Remote Enable permission on the server that runs the synchronization service. Doing this enables the timer job to run successfully regardless of which server picks up the timer job.

To grant the farm account the Remote Enable permission to Microsoft FIM 2010

1.
On the server that is running the synchronization service, click Start.

2.
Click Run, type wmimgmt.msc, and then click OK.

3.
Right click WMI Control, and then click Properties.

4.
In the WMI Control Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.

5.
Expand the Root list, and then select the Microsoft FIM 2010 namespace MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer.

6.
Click the Security button.

7.
Add the farm account to the list of groups and users, and then in the Permissions for Authenticated Users box, select Allow for the Remote Enable permission.

8.
 Click OK to dismiss the Security for ROOT\MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer dialog box, and then click OK to dismiss the WMI Control Properties dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, follow this:

1. Go to Central Administration
2. Application management - manage service applications
3. Select your User Profile Service and from the ribbon select Properties icon
4. Find Profile Synchronization instance field and select your UPS server there.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sharepoint2010setup/thread/212bfc67-27e8-4bc9-8e2b-bb8ba07affee

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your suggestion but i'd already checked this out and the correct server is selected for Profile Synchronization instance in both User Profile Service Application.

Answer (score 0):

We have 3-tire Architecture of SharePoint 2013(APP Server,WFE Server and SQL Server).I have configured User Profile Synchronization service in APP Server it is working and According to our requirement I have to configure one more User Profile Synchronization service for another Domain.By following below link I have configured secound UPS.

http://arindamchat.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-create-multiple-user-profile.html

But In Profile Synchronization status it is in "Synchronization" mode only for hours.

And I have gone through the Event Viewer in that i was facing following error.

**The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob (ID ff8f5626-9d40-4fd7-b3f1-f09a1080e701) threw an exception. More information is included below.
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)**

Again to solve this issues i have followed the steps which are mention in this Link.

[User Profile Incremental Synchronization Timer Job runs on wrong server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42830/user-profile-incremental-synchronization-timer-job-runs-on-wrong-server)

But still i was facing the same error and Profile Synchronization status is still 
"Synchronization".

Kindly Share you solution according to error message as above mention

Answer (score 0):

If you have a farm with more than one server;you have to disable the firewall on the server on which User Profile Syncronization runs.