# creating multiple User Profile Service Application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile

We have 3-tire Architecture of SharePoint 2013(APP Server,WFE Server and SQL Server).I have configured User Profile Synchronization service in APP Server it is working and According to our requirement I have to configure one more User Profile Synchronization service for another Domain.By following below link I have configured secound UPS.

http://arindamchat.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-create-multiple-user-profile.html

But In Profile Synchronization status it is in "Synchronization" mode only for hours.

And I have gone through the Event Viewer in that i was facing following error.

The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob (ID ff8f5626-9d40-4fd7-b3f1-f09a1080e701) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Again to solve this issues i have followed the following Link.

[User Profile Incremental Synchronization Timer Job runs on wrong server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42830/user-profile-incremental-synchronization-timer-job-runs-on-wrong-server)

But still i was facing the same error and Profile Synchronization status is still "Synchronization".

Answer (score 2):

You can only run one instance of the User Profile Sync Service per Server. Have you made certain that your server assignments in Services on Server are correct?

Ref: [Is it possible to have multiple User Profile Service Applications on a single server farm](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c922d0a8-db7f-4bdd-87a2-686c836bf406/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-user-profile-service-applications-on-a-single-server-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: We have requirement of two my site of two different forest for that we are created two user profile sync service.And both are no running same server(i.e., one is running in APP server and another is WFE server).