# User Profile Incremental Synchronization Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

I am quite new to SharePoint administration. On our production environment (1App server, 1 Web server and database on another server) the User Profile Synchronization service is not running. I tried to run the incremental sync explicitly. However in 2 seconds it fails. I gives error message 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Kindly let know what i am missing / doing incorrect.

I checked this post but didn't understood it
[enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42830/user-profile-incremental-synchronization-timer-job-runs-on-wrong-server)

"Edited"

I looked at ULS for more details and fond below error message

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob (ID
>   f26917a0-d30c-4187-b523-8f41f49c3fc0) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.  Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

The user account used in Profile sync config is '**sp_admin**'

Also the service was previously running correctly. Has started failing since last few days.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

Under "Manage" User Profile Service Application check if you configured everything correctly under "Configure Synchronization Connections". **IMPORTANT:** The Account you entered there must have **Replicate Directory Changes** permission in the Active Directory.

In order to run a sync. The User Profile Synchronization service must be running on a server. To start the Service go to "CA" -> "System Settings" -> "Manage services on server" and choose your App Server in the upper right corner. Start the User Profile Synchronization on the Server and the User Profile Service in case it is not running. On the Web Server the User Profile Service can be stopped.

Now try again to start a sync.

Comment: SunP, thanks for the reply. I checked for Replicate Directory Changes permission. the user sp_admin has that permission (allowed). Also checked for the services they are running. Kindly suggest if any thing am missing

Answer (score 0):

Check your UPSA service account access on UPSA databases [Sync DB, Social DB & Profile DB]. It should have full control / owner access on this databases.

Regards
PT

Comment: Prasad thank you for the reply. sp_admin account is owner for all these databases. Kindly let know if any other thing missed by me.